# unable to connect on postgres with a user created on php

Tags: php, postgresql

when i create a user from Postgres i could connect on php with `pg_connect`but when i create a user from a php page like

```
<?php
$host        = "host=localhost";
$dbname      = "dbname=cloud-personnel";
$user        = "user=postgres ";
$pass        = "password=root";
$port        = "port=5432";
$db=pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname $user $pass"  );
$alias = $_POST["alias"] ;
$categorie = $_POST["cat"] ;
$pass = $_POST["password"] ;
$sql = "UPDATE utilisateur SET  nom_groupe = '$categorie', type_user='' WHERE alias='$alias'";
$sql2 = "create user $alias with password '$pass';";
$sql3 = "alter group $categorie add user $alias";
$result = pg_query($sql);
pg_query($sql2);
pg_query($sql3);
header("location: ajoutuser.php");
?>
```

the user is created on postgres as a role the same like i could add with create user but when i try to connect with pg_connect i have this error message "Warning: pg_connect() [function.pg-connect]: Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: authentification par mot de passe échouée pour l'utilisateur"

any solution?

thank you

Comment: Is that a typo or is the code copied and pasted? The $sql2 variable doesn't close the password in '' It should be create user $alias with password '$pass';

Comment: I'm sorry about that I did not know before.
thanks for your help Daniel Casserly that was a mistake when i copied my code but it doesn't work .

Comment: It's a way of giving thanks to the person who helped solve an issue. *Cheers*